# How to debug "quotes is not defined" error in Chrome Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I keep getting an error in Chrome Tools that "quotes is not defined". I can find the solution. When I click to have Chrome Tools to show me the error it ends up in the `Math.floor`-`Math.random`.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
<h1>Random quote Generator</h1>


<br>
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">New Quote</button>

<a href="#" id="tweet" class="btn btn-primary">Tweet Out!</a>
<br>
<div class="quotes">
    <span class="quote"></span>
    <span class="author"></span>
</div>

</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

function getQuote(){
var quotes = ["With the new day comes new strength and new thoughts.", "War is 
peace. Freedom is slavery. Ignorance is strength.", "The goal of education is 
the advancement of knowledge and the dissemination of truth.", "Success is 
getting what you want. Happiness is wanting what you get." , "You know an odd 
feeling? Sitting on the toilet eating a chocolate candy bar."];
var author = ["-Eleanor Roosevelt", "George Orwell", "John F. Kennedy", "Dale 
Carnegie", "George Carlin"];
};

  var randumNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

  $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
  $(".author").text(randomAuthor);

  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
  getQuote();
  });

 });
```

Comment: You have declared `quotes` insides the function `getQuote()` and using it outside

Comment: Search for _variable scope_.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes variable is defined within method getQuotes(), thus is not visible outside. I assume your getQuote function is closed too early, simply move `}` after setting author.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function getQuote(){
    var quotes = ["With the new day comes new strength and new thoughts.", "War is 
             peace. Freedom is slavery. Ignorance is strength.", "The goal of education is 
             the advancement of knowledge and the dissemination of truth.", "Success is 
             getting what you want. Happiness is wanting what you get." , "You know an odd 
            feeling? Sitting on the toilet eating a chocolate candy bar."];

     var author = ["-Eleanor Roosevelt", "George Orwell", "John F. Kennedy", "Dale 
Carnegie", "George Carlin"];

  var randumNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

  $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
  $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
 };


 $(".btn").on("click", function(){
   getQuote();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you ended the `getQuote` function too early. Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function getQuote(){
var quotes = ["With the new day comes new strength and new thoughts.", "War is 
peace. Freedom is slavery. Ignorance is strength.", "The goal of education is 
the advancement of knowledge and the dissemination of truth.", "Success is 
getting what you want. Happiness is wanting what you get." , "You know an odd 
feeling? Sitting on the toilet eating a chocolate candy bar."];
var author = ["-Eleanor Roosevelt", "George Orwell", "John F. Kennedy", "Dale 
Carnegie", "George Carlin"];

  var randumNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

  $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
  $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
};

  $(".btn").on("click", function(){
  getQuote();
  });

 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I copied and pasted your code into my editor and I get an error  saying that I'm missing the ")" where I need to close after ending $(".author").text(randomAuthor);...and when I add the brace it goes back to giving me the error about the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

your getQuote function closes only defining 2 veriables 'quotes' and 'author' outside the funcion youre trying to read its values and thats not possible, so thats why you get th quotes undefined, you need to close your function (};) after this line of code

```
$(".author").text(randomAuthor);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function getQuote(){
    var quotes = ["With the new day comes new strength and new thoughts.", "War is peace. Freedom is slavery. Ignorance is strength.", "The goal of education is the advancement of knowledge and the dissemination of truth.", "Success is getting what you want. Happiness is wanting what you get." , "You know an odd feeling? Sitting on the toilet eating a chocolate candy bar."];

     var author = ["-Eleanor Roosevelt", "George Orwell", "John F. Kennedy", "Dale Carnegie", "George Carlin"];

  var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*quotes.length));
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  var randomAuthor = author[randomNum];

  $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
  $(".author").text(randomAuthor);
 };


 $(".btn").on("click", function(){
   getQuote();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">click me and see</button>

<p class="quotes"></p>
<p><small class="author"></small></p>
```

EDIT: Heres your snippet up and running just fine with the tweaks we all mention but one and its that you have a variable called 'randumNum and then you try to read the value as 'randomNum' (u and o)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...I have done what you mentioned and now I get a red "x" next to the closing bracket saying I'm missing a ")" symbol. When trying to add one in I get an error going back to the quotes.

Comment: if works unless you forgot to delete your previous close after authors

Comment: the error is not on the code snippet as the comment above shows the code modified as i intend to expain, and working just fine on a blank javascript file, your problem is on a different line in your code and its triggering when you fix this one

Comment: aniway just take a look at the live demo i attach in the edited version of this post